# Is the global inequality as measured by the Gini index rising or falling?

Tags: economics

Olle Hammar et al write in [Global Earnings Inequality, 1970–2015](http://ftp.iza.org/dp10762.pdf):

> Our  main  finding  is  that  global  earnings  inequality  has 
>   declined,  primarily  during  the  2000s,   when  the  global  Gini 
>   coefficient  dropped  nearly  10  points  and  the  earnings  share 
>   of   the  world’s  poorest  half  doubled.

[GlobalFinance](https://www.gfmag.com/global-data/economic-data/wealth-distribution-income-inequality) writes:

> Today, data shows that the gap between the richest and the poorest has
>   never been wider.

What's true? Is the popular conception that inequality as measured by metrics such as the Gini-index rises false as Hammar claims or is it true?

Comment: Your question assumes that the gap between the richest an poorest ist the same as the gini coefficient. That is probably not the case.

Comment: I posted an answer but then deleted it because I wasn't satisfied. But here are some hopefully helpful remarks from it: 1. (labor) earnings are not the same as income, which shifts the gini considerably (wealthy people are more likely to have income from capital). 2. A gini index is just one metric, and it is difficult to draw conclusions about the underlying distributions from it. 3. The [world inequality report](https://wir2018.wid.world/files/download/wir2018-full-report-english.pdf) states "At the global level, inequality has risen sharply since 1980".

Comment: Graphs for Gini coefficient by country are found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Relative* inequality has fallen over the last four decades; *absolute* inequality has increased, according to the [University of Oxford](http://www.ox.ac.uk/news/2016-08-25-global-income-inequality-down-relative-terms-absolute-sums)

Say in 1975 Alice earned $1 a year and Bob earned $100 a year. Bob earns 100x Alice's income in relative terms, and earns $99 a year more in absolute terms.

A decade goes by and Bob's income doubles. Alice's income quadruples over the same time span, so Alice earns $4 / year, and Bob $200 / year. Now in relative terms, Bob only earns 50x Alice's income - relative inequality has halved. But he also earns $196 more than her, nearly double the absolute inequality.

I cannot say with confidence that the sources you're quoting are falling afoul of this distinction, but it's one explanation for the difference.

Comment: "inequality"  is always relative. I'd rephrase this to say "multiplicative" vs "additive" or something along those lines.

Comment: I agree with @einpoklum. Seeing as buying power is something that is calculated multiplicatively, I would say that the relative measure is more important.

Comment: The University of Oxford press release / study I linked specifically uses the phrase 'relative (global) inequality' and 'absolute inequality'.